# CQL3 Show Column Families

Tags: cassandra, cql3, column-family

Can anybody tell how to get a list of column families under the current key space in Cassandra  2.0.4?

Kindly note that am using `cqlsh` to query the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Svend's very concise answer, you can also query `system.schema_columnfamilies` with the name of the keyspace in question:

```
SELECT columnfamily_name 
FROM system.schema_columnfamilies
WHERE keyspace_name='myKeyspaceName';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
desc tables;
```

Also, not that cqlsh support tab-completion (à la bash), so pressing  in the middle of a `use` or `select`statement also provides available parameter values.